# How to create a classifier from different set of data derived from the same image

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I am trying to create a classifier in order to differentiate between men and women from face images.
For each image I have 4 sets of data (one for the whole face, eyes, nose and lips) witch are the same.

That means for each image i have 4 of the same features but they are derived from different parts of the image.

Is it possible to incorporate them into one classifier, or should I create 4 classifiers and then combine them.
Something else, these data that I have, should I use everything, or should I stick to the statisticly different ones (from a T-test).

I am sorry it is hard to explain, and its my first time posting here.

Comment: I think you should try a different community. Please have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266067/difference-between-the-cross-validated-and-data-science-se-sites and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms

Answer (score -1):

You could train a single classifier which takes as input the stacked images of the eyes, nose, and lips. This is only possible if these images have the same shape. The kind of model you may want to use would be a convolutional neural network, as it can efficiently handle image data.

If I may ask, what is the reason that you have to use the separate eyes, nose, and lips features if you already have an image of the full face?

Comment: It was a suggestion my supervisor gave me. I believe he kind of wants me to create a classifier that takes data from all the pictures in order to create a better result

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I would use only the images of the whole faces as input in a CNN. Let the network extract itself the features it needs to differentiate between men and women. By feeding the model specific images of noses, eyes and lips, you are already kind of 'hard-coding' features for your classification, by making the assumption that these three body parts are all the computer needs to see in order to make a decision.

Comment: Unfortunately i have to use the data I have for the cassification.